# How To Validate WPF Datagrid Rows Properly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, desktop-application

I am trying to use a WPF Datagrid as an input for a chart data.. I need some of it's columns to only accept integers and others strings... I assigned an ObservableCollection to it and everything works fine. Even the integer filtering... But I want to disable the Save Button that saves the information taken as inputs until all the values of a row validated properly and I don't have a hint on how to do that...

Here is my code for the datagrid...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestTable" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding firstname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding lastname}"/>
        <DataGrid.Columns/>
</DataGrid>
```

C# Data Class for Datagrid..........

```
public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Data> _datas;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> datas
    {
        get { return _datas ?? (_datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>()); }
        set { _datas = value; }
    }
}
```

Main Class.......

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new Data();
        TestTable.DataContext = data;
        TestTable.ItemsSource = data.datas;
    }
```

What Should I do to properly keep the save button disabled until getting all the datas validated?

Comment: How are you validating grid data? code post doesn't show any validation.

Comment: Did you already checked the data grid validation? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control

Comment: Yes I did... I am not separately using any rule for validation... Any wrong type of input is shown as a red border around the cell.. I am using the default validation rule.. I just want to prevent the user from saving the infos with wrong data.. So I want to disable the save button until all data is validated...